# how to incorporate try and except into a block of code in python

Tags: python

I am working on a collatz sequence code in python. The code should give me a sequence of numbers that end in 1. The code I have here does that when I enter a number.

```
    try:
    number = int(input('Pick a number'))
except ValueError:
    print('Error! input a number')
def collatz(number):
            if number % 2 == 0:
                x = number // 2
                return x
            else:
                x = 3 * number + 1
                return x

while number != 1:
        number = collatz(number)
        print(number)
```

However, when I try to invoke the try and except function by entering a letter,I get the desired error message but I also get a NameError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/collatz/collatz.py", line 14, in <module>
    while number != 1:
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
Error! input a number *Desired Error Message*
```

I dont get this error when I remove the try and except function. I have tried defining 'name' as a global variable and also played around with the indentation but nothing seems to work. I would greatly appreciate any kind of help.

I am using python 3.6.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) may be of interest to you

Comment: your problem is not variable `name` but variable `number`. When you enter letter then you get error and code in `try` doesn't create variable `number` - so later you have error `"number" is not defined` for line `while number != 1:`. You have to define `number` with some default value inside `except` or before `try`

Comment: @furas I understand what you are saying but I am not exactly sure how to implement it into a code. If its not too much trouble, can you show me how you would do that?

Comment: there is nothing to show. Simply use `number =  1` before `try` and it will create variable `number` with default value `1` - so  `number` will exist even when you enter letter. And this resolve problem with `'number' is not defined`.

Comment: Thank you @furas That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the NameError is because `number` is simply not defined. The call to `int` fails, thus the assignment to `number` never happens, you catch and print the error but then just proceed. To force the user to enter a valid number you have to repeat the prompt until the user enters the correct input.

```
def read_number():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Pick a number'))
        except ValueError:
            print('Error! Input a number')
```

Then, to read a sequence of numbers you do:

```
while True:
    number = read_number()
    if number == 1:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `ValueError` get raised, then I think you don't really define `number` in any other place. That's why your `while` loop raises a `NameError`.